# CakePHP 3.x - Extension router in prefix only

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0, prefix

I am developing an application which has a side available to users (the dashboard) and a back-end side (an API). I want the API side to have pages which output JSON. Thanks to Cake this is made easy with a `$this->set('_serialize', [...]);` from a controller in combination with a router setting: `Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);`. I use prefix routing to group the API pages.

**Question: how can I make only the API pages support the `*.json` pages from the extensions router?**

*Things I tried*

- Putting the `Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);` line in the routes.php main scope makes it work everywhere, obviously.
- Putting the `Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);` line inside the prefix scope...

  ```
  Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
       //...
       Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);
       //...
  });
  ```

  ...Makes it work everywhere *but* inside the API prefix.
- Putting it in a new scope...

  ```
  Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
     $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
  });
  ```

  ...Also makes it work everywhere.

Comment: Have you read **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions**?

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixes are scopes too, just with additional functionality (it's basically a shorthand method for `scope()` and passing the `prefix` option). In fact, every route is scoped, even if not explicitly connected via the `scope()` method.

Use the routes builder that is passed to the callback for the `prefix()` method, just as shown in the `scope()` example in the docs and your question:

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    // ...
});
```

And make sure that you do not use `Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);` anywhere.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routes > Routing File Extensions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)**

Comment: Ah, that did the trick. The mistake I made was using `Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);` instead of `$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);`